# Email limit on SMTP when the sender and receiver are under the same domain

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, limits

In the company I work at, I have to setup our backend application to send a big amount of emails with updates to a customer (we have permission for that), but without using any 3rd party service apart from the current one that our company uses. 
Obviously, our current email service provider has a limit on outgoing emails which I asked them to increase for the purposes of the application. They warned me though, that if the server gets blacklisted they'll have to decrease the limit again.

The customer has its own domain name (`example.com`) and email service provider, and I was wondering if they provide me with an account under their domain name (`a@example.com`), will there be a limit on how many outgoing emails I can send to one of the email addresses on the same domain name (`b@example.com`) or is there any risk of getting any of the servers involved blacklisted?

TL;DR Is there a limit on how many emails you can send from `a@example.com` to `b@example.com` or any other issue that might arise if "too many" emails get sent?

Comment: If any such limits are set, those limits  won’t be generic. Fairly typical is that rate limiting measures will result in a ***temporary*** delivery error that at the smtp level for the sender. That will result in a retry and delayed delivery but nothing worse. _-_  The worse scenario is that exceeding a set rate limit will result in an increased spam score and that will result in delivery problems

Comment: From my research I thought that in the scenario that the sender is `c@diffdomain.com` and the receiver is `b@example.com`, then in case the limit is reached, the SMTP server rejects the email with a 554 5.7.0 error and there is not any retry:`If a message was blocked by the outgoing mail control, it does not get queued or saved, it just gets rejected (dropped) without the ability to resend it. This is done to prevent spamming on a server`: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213389069-What-will-happen-to-emails-that-are-sent-over-the-limitations-on-outgoing-email-messages

Comment: Is it different if the sender and the receiver are both under the same domain? If so, and it's like you describe, then the email server registered under the domain name `example.com` would black list/increase the spam score for itself? @HBruijn